# Problems with 'fs' when I try to start snowpack

Tags: node.js, snowpack

> [15:03:25] [snowpack] Welcome to Snowpack! Because this is your first
> time running this project, Snowpack needs to prepare your
> dependencies. This is a one-time step and the results will be cached
> for the lifetime of your project. Please wait... [15:03:25] [snowpack]
> Package "fs" not found. Have you installed it?

When I try to start snowpack I got the error above...
Is 'fs' not include in node by default? When I tried to install 'fs' via npm install fs, not started as well. Some of my files(test files) use 'fs' to run some tests...

Obs: I am using to import:

```
import fs from 'fs';//(not require('fs'))
```

Thanks. André

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to deal with it in the snowpack website using the configuration in snowpack.config.js (packageOptions.external: ["fs", "path"])

```
module.exports = {

  packageOptions: {
    /* ... */
    external: ["fs", "path"]
  }
}
```